# Objective c, equivalent for CopyTo in C#

Tags: objective-c

I have a C# code, which copy bytes to a byte Array, from specific index, as following example illustrates:

```
string headerInfo = String.Format(source + "<>" + destination + "<>" + sessionId);
headerInfo = headerInfo.TrimEnd('\n', '\0', '\r');
byte[] headerInfoBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(headerInfo);
byte[] headerInfoLength = BitConverter.GetBytes(headerInfo.Length);

//create an byte Array with proper size.
byte[] sendData = new byte[4 + 4 + headerInfoBytes.Length + dataContractBytes.Length];

headerInfoLength.CopyTo(sendData, 0);
dataContractLengthBytes.CopyTo(sendData, 4);
headerInfoBytes.CopyTo(sendData, 8);
dataContractBytes.CopyTo(sendData, 8 + headerInfoBytes.Length);
m_clientSocket.Send(sendData);
```

my question is, how I can achive the CopyTo in objective c way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/BinaryData/Tasks/WorkingMutableData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002150) on how to handle mutable data.

If you specifically need the index part, you can use `replaceBytesInRange:withBytes:`. Otherwise, just append the data:

```
NSString *headerInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<>%@<>%@", source, destination, sessionId];
NSData *headerData = [headerInfo dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:headerData.length + ...];
[data appendData:headerData];
```